# How to receive Wcf status in response

Tags: web-services, wcf

I created WCF Services and  I'm using `DoSomething()` method like this:

```
 public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        WebOperationContext _ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
        _ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

    }
}
```

Furthermore, I need read "ok" status in my code when I'm using this service:

```
 ServiceClient _serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
            _serviceClient.DoSomething();

            WebOperationContext _ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
            var statusObj = _ctx.IncomingResponse.StatusCode;
```

I found that `_ctx` is **null**

I would like to ask you how to read status in my  `statusObj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this ,**

**Soap end point :**

```
WCFServiceClient soapClient = new WCFServiceClient();
            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(soapClient.InnerChannel))
            {
                    soapClient.DoSomething();
                    var response = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["httpResponse"];
                    var status = response.StatusCode;
            }
```

**Rest end point :**

```
 var client = new RestClient("service-url/rest/DoSomething");
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var status = response.StatusCode;
        }
```